# Checkbox inside *ngIf panel not trigger with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-ng-if, ngmodel

It seems that the checkboxes inside an *ngIf condition don't trigger the event. I tried to reproduce the problem here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-uoxd3q

As you can see, we are a main component:

```
<div class="fake-accordion" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" (click)="item.expanded = !item.expanded">
  <div class="head">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  <app-details (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); $event.preventDefault()" *ngIf="item.expanded" [item]="item">
  </app-details>
</div>
```

that loops some items. Inside this loop there's another component for the details. It opens only if item.expanded is true. Inside that there are some checkboxes

```
<div class="details-body">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.flag1" />Flag1
  </div>

   <div>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.flag2" />Flag2
  </div>

   <div>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.flag3" />Flag3
  </div>
</div>
```

but when I try to change the model it doesn't work. I tried to remove this line:

```
(click)="$event.stopPropagation(); $event.preventDefault()"
```

but in this way the detail component closes when i click somewhere inside it. Anyway, it's not working too. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$event.preventDefault()` from your `click` handler inside `app-details`.

```
<app-details (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" *ngIf="item.expanded" [item]="item">
</app-details>
```

> The Event interface's [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method tells the user agent
>   that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action
>   should not be taken as it normally would be.